# inline assembly genericity over operand width

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

My goal is to observe the outputs (destination operand and eflag register) of several instructions like add, or, xor, and, sub, etc...

For this I am randomly feeding them with inputs, and record the outputs. I embed the target instruction into a C++ routine with some genericity over the widht/signedness of the operands:

```
/* generic operand.  
   W: width, S: signedness 
*/
templates<size_t W, bool S> gen_op { public: typedef size_t type;};
```

followed by specializations:

```
template<> gen_op<8U,true> { public: typedef int8_t type;};
...
template<> gen_op<16U,false> { public: typedef uint16_t type;};
...
```

and then:

```
template<size_t W, bool S>
gen_op<W,S>::type test_add(gen_op<W,S>::type i1, gen_op<W,S>::type i2)
{
    gen_op<W,S>::type o;
    {
        __asm movzx eax, i1
        __asm add eax, i2
        __asm mov o, eax
    }
    return o;
}
```

Another routine exists to test the eflag register using pushfd/pop. I know it would be more efficient (in time) to use only one routine and report the destination operand and the eflag register at once.

Since I am quite new to inline assembler (and to assembler as well), I would like to get your feedback on the approach/validity of results.

On my side, I see one issue: for the time being, I limit myself to 8/16/32 bit operand. But when moving to 64 bit operand, EAX will not be enough. How can I handle this in a simple manner ?

Comment: Since this looks like Visual Studio style inline assembler, you don't have to worry about 64-bit registers. Since 64-bit C compiler doesn't allow inline assembler.

Comment: @Mats: Thanks for the info. Though I use a 32-bit compiler on 64 bits hosts. Does it allows manipulation of 64bits registers ?

Comment: Nope. In 32-bit mode, you only get 8 x 32 bit registers, not the 16 x 64 bit that is available in 64-bit mode. [In fact, in 32-bit mode, the prefix (40-4F) that control 64-bit mode operations has a completely different meaning, and represent, from memory, the PUSH/POP instructions for the common registers - which also have a duplicate encoding in the 0xFF XX opcode range, which is the one you get in 64-bit mode].